# How does Linux traverse its device tree?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

If I understand correctly, Linux [organizes devices](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/master/labs/device_model.html) in a tree-like structure with nodes of type `struct kobject`:

```
struct kobject {
    struct list_head    entry;
    struct kobject      *parent;
    struct kset         *kset;
    // ...
};
```

It has fields:

- `parent`, which points to its parent `struct kobject`
- `kset`, pointer to the `struct kset` of the related kobjects
- `entry`, looks like it's needed to maintain ksets, but I'm not sure

These fields point either to parent object or to the objects of the same level. None of them point to the child nodes. Omitted fields do not seem to relate to the issue.

Given all that, how does Linux traverse its device tree without having nodes explicitly pointing to their children?

Comment: What kind of devices, and what "device tree", are you referring to?

Comment: @duskwuff I added a link. I am talking about linux device model.

Comment: What makes you think it needs to traverse the device tree from the top?

Comment: @Barmar I assumed that it would need some kind of maintenance. Also, how does the kernel create entries in `sysfs`? If it relies only on `struct device` and `struct bus` for that, that why even bother adding hierarchy to kobects?

Comment: I assume it's like a class hierarchy in an OOP language. Subclasses need to refer to their superclasses, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Barmar But `parent` is of a same type. And a kset is basically a list of kobjects

Comment: https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/master/labs/device_model.html says **Structure fields include the parent device that is usually a controller**

Comment: Looks like there's lots of good information on that page. Googling "linux device hierarchy" finds other relevant pages.

Comment: So device and bus structures make up device tree, class structures - class tree. Then, I guess, kobjects and ksets and just required data structures for reference counting and do not form a hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, you need to get in OOP to understand the concept (surprise, surprise, but C language allows to write an OOP code and supports inheritance via simple tricks). Besides that, there is no single device tree in the Linux kernel. Of course, it’s possible theoretically to find a platform on which it would be like that, but as of my knowledge there is none of real existing case.

Comment: @0andriy I was under impression that there's exactly one kernel device tree after looking at the [uboot model](https://www.denx.de/wiki/pub/U-Boot/MiniSummitELCE2014/dm-u-boot.pdf) (which was inspired by Linux). I cannot see any downside it. Its structure would be similar to one, supplied by [device tree](https://www.devicetree.org/). Why is it not the case?

Comment: I am talking about device tree(s) in the concept of Linux device model. Sorry for confusion, it has nothing to do with Device Tree as a part of Open Firmware specifications.

Comment: @0andriy yes, I understood that. It just makes sense to mirror the structure of the one onto another

Comment: Linux kernel was designed along with its device model much earlier than Device Tree and OF jumped into the play. Moreover, most of the (desktop / server) platforms are completely Device Tree-free. How can you do that on them? (Above is just a very partial to the question, there are more issues with that)

Comment: @0andriy it's not that desktop and server peripherals cannot be expressed in form of DeviceTree data structure, they just usually don't need it because of the runtime device discovery mechanisms. But for some embedded chip buses it's not possible. Anyway, maybe you can recommend some resources on the issue (besides reading the kernel sources)?

Comment: I don't see any issue here, perhaps you need to reformulate your question.

Comment: The device tree properties/bindings(key-value pairs) are parsed, populated and then propagated to BSP/driver files by set of files below: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.14/source/drivers/of (I took 4.14.14 kernel as e.g.)